# Discrete choice model with autoregressive error term

Tags: inference, autoregressive, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling

I consider consumer choice over time $t$ over a set of alternatives $J$, whereby a consumer's perceived utility of option $j$ is

$u_{jt}=x_{j}+\mu_{jt}$

with $\mu_{j0}=\epsilon_{j0}\sim\mathcal{F}(\sigma)$ (for example a normal distribution or a Gumbel distribution with $\sigma$ a precision parameter) and

$\mu_{jt}=\rho\mu_{j(t-1)}+\epsilon_{jt}$, with $\epsilon_{jt}\sim\mathcal{F}(\sigma)$ iid.

We observe the consumer's choice $y_{jt}$, whereby $y_{jt}=1$ if $u_{jt}>\underset{k}{\max}(u_{kt})$.

There will thus be autocorrelation in the choices made over time. How do I infer the value of $\rho$ from those choices?